# How do I access a parent's methods inside a child's constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

Say I have `class child()` and `class parent()`. The parent has a constructor and a few other public methods, and the child is empty apart from a constructor.

How do I go about calling a parent's methods inside of the child's constructor, as in:

```
Class Parent {
    public function __construct() {
       // Do stuff (set up a db connection, for example)
    }

    public function run($someArgument) {
       // Manipulation
       return $modifiedArgument;
    }
} 

Class Child extends Parent {
    public function __construct() {
      // Access parent methods here?
    }  
}
```

Say I want to call `parent`s `run()` method, do I have to call a new instance of the parent inside the child constructor? Like so...

```
$var = new Parent(); 
$var->run($someArgument);
```

If so, what is the point of `extends` from a class definition POV? I can call a new instance of another class with the `new` keyword whether it extends the 'child' or not.

My (likely) wrong understanding was that by using `extends` you can link classes and methods from a parent can be inherited into the child. Is that only *outside* the class definition? Does using `extend` offer no efficiencies inside the class definition?

Because referring to the parent's `run()` method with the `this` keyword certainly doesn't work...

Comment: But doesn't `$this` refer to only the child definition? I tried calling `$this->__construct();` as a reference to the parent constructor inside the child constructor and the errors PHP threw indicated it thought the object at hand was the child constructor itself.

Comment: With the `parent` keyword, funnily enough ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `parent` as predefined reference: `parent::run()`. This will ensure you call parent method. The same way you could call first parent constructor first or after child one - `parent::__construct()`.

```
Class Child extends Parent {
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      // Access parent methods here?
      $some_arg = NULL; // init from constructor argument or somewhere else
      parent::run($some_arg); // explicitly call parent method
      // $this->run($some_arg); // implicitly will call parent if no child override
    }
```

}

If you dont have an implementation in child you could call `$this->run($args)`, where it will again call parent run method.

Comment: wouldn't only `run()` suffice? As there isn't any `run()` implementation in `Child` class

Comment: Yes but if you have run in child it will run it and the questions is precisely for parent methods.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib not exactly. Imagine run() is a method which changes a value of a protected property. If its called from $this context, ($this->run()) it will change the value of the current class property.

Comment: @Rolice, if I'm using `parent::` to reference a parent class, I still have to call the parent constructor manually (via `parent::__construct()`, right? Not doing so throws a PHP error.

Comment: Yes in the child constructor, if he made some important operations (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

To extend Rolice's answer

```
function a() {
  echo 'I exist everywhere';
}
class A {
  protected $a
  function a() {
    $this->a = 'I have been called';
  }
  function out() {
    echo $this->a;
    a();
  }
}
class B extends A {
  function __construct() {
    parent::a();// original method
    $this->a(); // overridden method
    a();
  }
  function a() {
    $this->a = $this->a ? 'I have been overwritten' : 'first call';
  }
}
```

Study these to understand the difference