# How can I access the same name method in the parent class?

Tags: php, function, class, oop, inheritance

Here is a simplified of my code:

```
class questions {

    public function index( $one = '', $two = '', $three = '' ) {
        return 'sth';
    }
}


class tags extends questions {

    public function index () {
        return parentClass::index();
    }

}
```

But my code throws this error:

[image]

Does anybody know how can I fix the error?

[expected result is printing: `sth`](https://3v4l.org/hRBhT)

Comment: Check the code in autoloader.php...

Comment: Instead of `parentClass::index()` you should use `parent::index()` to call `questions::index()` from the `tags` class.

Comment: have u tried return questions::index();

Comment: There's no `parentClass` in your code. For accessing parents there's a keyword `parent`.

Comment: @Jocelyn `<?php function my_autoloader($class) { require_once($class.".php"); } spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader'); ?>`. Do you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: @u_mulder Oh, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php#3115398) made me wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access a parent's methods inside a child's constructor in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494518/how-do-i-access-a-parents-methods-inside-a-childs-constructor-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

If you extend a class and override a method, you must make sure the overridden method has the same "prototype", i.e., it must have the same number of method arguments in the same order. That's why you get the first warning:

> Warning: Declaration of tags::index() should be compatible with questions::index($query_where = '', $query_join = '', $called_from = NULL) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\tags.php** on line **3**

Second, if you want to call a function with the same name from the parent class, you'll need to use the `parent` keyword:

```
class tags extends questions {

    public function index ($query_where = '', $query_join = '', $called_from = NULL) {
        return parent::index($query_where, $query_join, $called_from);
    }

}
```